# Keyboard shortcut to resize window to full-screen (but not over unity dock)

Tags: shortcut-keys, launcher, wayland, window-manager, window-management

Is there a keyboard shortcut, or a way of defining a keyboard shortcut, that'll resize current window to take up whole screen except the unity dock?

(yes, I know I can make the unity dock stay always-on-top; and can then use F11 to make [most] current window take up whole screen; but then I lose clock)

I don't want to go overboard and install [xmonad](https://xmonad.org) (or similar) just for this simple functionality. BTW: I'm using Wayland and mainline kernel.

Comment: I am looking at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/103781 but the best suggestions are `xbindkeys` and `xdotool` involved; which I assume are X only; and also involve installing something new. I'm an admin, but literally just need one addition key shortcut; so should be able to avoid additional binaries?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to maximize a window, but keeping the top bar (clock), and showing the Dock. I assume you want this on a per-window basis, i.e., you press a shortcut, and the window is maximized displaying the dock. On another window, you press another shortcut key, and the window is maximized without showing the dock.

I also assume that you are not referring to the full screen state, which by purpose hides all desktop elements. I have to assume, because the question is not very clear.

You probably are aware that "full-screen mode" and the "maximized window state" are two different states.

- "full-screen" mode fills the entire screen, indeed covering the dock. The application may define a shortcut for that, quite commonly <kbd>F11</kbd>. A global keyboard shortcut can be set in "Settings" - "Keyboard".
- "maximized" will have the window occupy maximal space, not covering the dock, unless the dock is set to autohide itself when covered by a window. The default shortcut key to maximize a window is <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> will toggle between maximized and normal state.

As for your question, having a shortcut key that both maximized the window while showing the Dock will not be easy especially in Wayland. That is because the state of the window and the display of a dock are two independent settings. In X11, one can manipulate the window state with the tools `wmctrl` or `xdotool`. In Wayland, one cannot although one can expose dbus commands to manipulate windows using extensions.

You could consider creating a shortcut key that toggles the autohide setting of the dock. The command

```bash
gsettings get org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock intellihide
```

will retrieve the current setting. You can change the setting with the command, e.g.,

```bash
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock intellihide false
```

to turn it off.

With this knowledge, you can create a bash script that checks the current status of the setting, then changes it, then bind that script to a shortcut key.

Comment: <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> goes in front of the dock. As does <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>.

Comment: @AT Then you probably have autohide turned on.

Comment: Yes I do. So how do I get this to work with autohide on? - Because fullscreen is sometimes useful for the current app; but most of the time I want the dock ontop

Comment: It is your choice. Either you set the dock to autohide, and then it will hide when a window covers it (such as a maximized window), or you do not set that, then the dock remains visible. In all cases, the dock will not be visible in full screen mode.

Comment: Yes, but how do I create a keyboard shortcut to expand the current window to not go over the dock, but take up the rest of the whole screen otherwise?

Comment: You cannot unless you are a very good programmer. I updated my answer, hoping it will make the current situation and why what you wish (if at least I understand it correctly) is not easily possible, especially on Wayland.